# best way to join query fields, union all/union

Tags: sql-server, select

I have 4 fields
cnpj 1
cnpj 2
cnpj 3
cnpj 4
all with the same typing, these fields go through an IN filter, for that I use UNION ALL in all 4 fields, is there a way to do this without union all ? or is it really the best way?

```
 select id
 from ( select id from db_armazenamento..arquivo_conhecimento 
 WITH(INDEX(IX_arquivo_conhecimento_6),nolock)         
        where dta_inclusao between getdate () -20 and getdate () 
and cpf_cnpj_emitente COLLATE database_default in (SELECT cnpj from 
  db_armazenamento..INTEGRA_ORCL_CTE)
    union all
select id from db_armazenamento..arquivo_conhecimento 
WITH(INDEX(IX_arquivo_conhecimento_6),nolock)         
        where dta_inclusao between getdate () -20 and getdate () 
and cpf_cnpj_destinatario COLLATE database_default in (SELECT cnpj from 
db_armazenamento..INTEGRA_ORCL_CTE)
    union all 
select id from db_armazenamento..arquivo_conhecimento 
WITH(INDEX(IX_arquivo_conhecimento_6),nolock)         
        where dta_inclusao between getdate () -20 and getdate () 
and cpf_cnpj_remetente COLLATE database_default in (SELECT cnpj from 
db_armazenamento..INTEGRA_ORCL_CTE)
   union all
select id from db_armazenamento..arquivo_conhecimento 
WITH(INDEX(IX_arquivo_conhecimento_6),nolock)         
        where dta_inclusao between getdate () -20 and getdate () 
  and cpf_cnpj_recebedor COLLATE database_default in (SELECT cnpj from 
  db_armazenamento..INTEGRA_ORCL_CTE)       
) as c
```

Comment: "Best way" is quite subjective. Fastest execution? Lowest CPU? Lowest IO? Most readable? Also depends on the results you want. Your existing query will return duplicate rows if there are matches in more than one part of the union. Is this the desired behaviour? This also may be worth a read: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). I'd be very wary of using `WITH INDEX` too. Unless you are **certain** you know better than the optimiser, I would let it do it's thing.

Comment: The fact that you are using both forced index hints *and* `NOLOCK` suggests a problem; normally SQL Server is far better at choosing what index to use. The fact you are both telling it to use a specific index *and* to not care about incorrect data suggests misuse of both hints.

Comment: Formatting your code so that it is readable (rather than a wall of text) will encourage others to examine it in a meaningful way

Comment: In addition to what @GarethD already stated, those date shorthands are not great. You really should be using dateadd. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations  And between can be truly evil.....especially with datetime values. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't know why you keep selecting the rows over and over and over from the same table and then compare them to different columns be equal in another table. Pretty sure you could simplify the whole thing into something like this.

```
SELECT ac.id
    FROM db_armazenamento.dbo.arquivo_conhecimento ac --you really should be explicit with the schema instead of relying on the default
    join db_armazenamento.dbo.INTEGRA_ORCL_CTE ioc on ioc.cnpj in 
                                                            (
                                                                ac.cpf_cnpj_emitente
                                                                , ac.cpf_cnpj_destinatario
                                                                , ac.cpf_cnpj_remetente
                                                                , ac.cpf_cnpj_recebedor
                                                            )
where ac.dta_inclusao >= dateadd(day, -20, getdate()
    and ac.dta_inclusao <= getdate()
```